# How to do JPQL with JOIN FETCH to collect the multiple JOINs in one query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How to write JPQL with JOIN FETCH to grab all the **Post** collection and associated tags & items & subitems in one call without N+1 query from database.

Entities

```
@Entity
public class Post {
  @Id
  private String postId;
  private String postName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Collection<PostTag> postTags = new HashSet<PostTag>();
}
@Entity
public class Tag {
  @Id
  private String tagId;
  private String tagName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Collection<PostTag> postTags = new HashSet<PostTag>();
}
@Entity
public class PostTag {
  @EmbeddedId
  private PostTagId postTagId = new PostTagId();
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("postId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "post_Id")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Post post;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("tagId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "tag_Id")
  private Tag tag;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "posttag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Items> items= new HashSet<Items>();

  private String someDateField;
}
@Embeddable
public class PostTagId implements Serializable {
  private String postId;
  private String tagId;
  //equals & hashcode ommited
}
public class Items{
  @Id
  private String itemId;
  private String itemName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "post_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
  @JsonBackReference
  @JsonIgnore
  private PostTag postTag;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "items", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<SubItems> subItems= new HashSet<SubItems>();

}
public class SubItems{
  @Id
  private String subItemId;
  private String subItemName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "itemId")})
  @JsonBackReference
  @JsonIgnore
  private Items items;

}
```

JPA findAll() triggers so many join queries which is 1 query per result per table. for example if 1 association is there in all the table 4 total queries being triggered.

Have tried,

```
@Query("select po from Post po inner join fetch PostTag pt on po.postId=pt.post.postId inner join fetch Tag t on pt.tag.tagId = t.tagId")
Page<Post> findAllInOneQuery(Pageable pageable);
```

But this results in exception. what is the right way to get all the collections in one shot using JOIN FETCH with @Query command?

**Note:**
Plain findAll() triggers bellow queries for 1 result with all association.

```
Hibernate: select post0_.postId as postid1_0_, post0_.postName as postname2_0_ from post post0_ inner join PostTag posttag1_ on post0_.postId=posttag1_.post_id inner join tagInfo taginfo2_ on posttag1_.tag_id=taginfo2_.tagId left outer join PostTag posttag3_ on post0_.postId=posttag3_.post_id where (taginfo2_.tagName like ?) and (posttag1_.someDateField between ? and ?) order by posttag3_.someDateField desc, posttag3_.pubDate desc offset 0 rows fetch next ? rows only
    
    Hibernate: select posttag0_.post_id as post_id1_4_0_, posttag0_.tag_id as tag_i2_4_0_, posttag0_.post_id as post_id1_4_1_, posttag0_.tag_id as tag_i2_4_1_, posttag0_.content as content3_4_1_, posttag0_.someDateField as someDateField10_4_1_ from PostTag posttag0_ where posttag0_.post_id=?
    
    Hibernate: select items0_.post_id as post_id3_1_0_, items0_.tag_id as tag_i4_1_0_, items0_.productId as producti1_1_0_, items0_.productId as producti1_1_1_, items0_.productName as productn2_1_1_, items0_.post_id as post_id3_1_1_, items0_.tag_id as tag_i4_1_1_ from Items items0_ where items0_.post_id=? and items0_.tag_id=?
    
    Hibernate: select subitems0_.productId as producti3_3_0_, subitems0_.subitemId as subitemi1_3_0_, subitems0_.subitemId as subitemi1_3_1_, subitems0_.productId as producti3_3_1_, subitems0_.subitemName as subitemn2_3_1_ from SubItems subitems0_ where subitems0_.productId=?
    
    Hibernate: select count(post0_.postId) as col_0_0_ from post post0_ inner join PostTag posttag1_ on post0_.postId=posttag1_.post_id inner join tagInfo taginfo2_ on posttag1_.tag_id=taginfo2_.tagId where (taginfo2_.tagName like ?) and (posttag1_.someDateField between ? and ?)
    
    Hibernate: select taginfo0_.tagId as tagid1_2_0_, taginfo0_.tagName as tagna2_2_0_ from tagInfo taginfo0_ where taginfo0_.tagId=?
```

How can i convert the above queries into one single JOIN fetch using @Query!!!!

**Solutions tried so far!!** (Not working)

```
@Query("select po.postId as postid1_0_, po.postName as postname2_0_ from post po inner join fetch PostTag pt1 inner join fetch tagInfo t left outer join fetch PostTag pt2 where (t.tagName like :tName) and (pt1.someDateField between :sDate and :eDate) order by pt2.someDateField desc")
Page<Post> findAllInOneQuery(String tName, String sDate, String eDate, Pageable pageable);
```

**Exception:**

```
illegal attempt to dereference collection [po.postId.posttag] with element property reference [someDateField]
```

Comment: You don't need the ON clause.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes i have removed ON clause but still i see some exceptions. added in original question

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@Query("select po from Post po join fetch po.postTags pt join fetch pt.tag t where (t.tagName like :tName) and exists(select 1 from po.postTags pt2 where pt2.someDateField between :sDate and :eDate) order by pt.someDateField desc")
Page<Post> findAllInOneQuery(String tName, String sDate, String eDate, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple queries to get all associated entities, otherwise you would end up with a very inefficient SQL query.

I suggest the following:

- Create a custom repository method [as described here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories)
- Make one fetch join per to-many association [as described here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/)

The reason for not doing it in 'one shot' is that your joins would end up with a cartesian product of all related rows, which is also the reason why you are (presumably) getting a `MultipleBagFetchException`.